# Setlength \parskip with \baselineskip

Tags: paragraphs

For me it does not work to specify a `plus` and `minus` in units of `pt` in the `setlength` option for `\parskip` with `\baselineskip`.

Why is that the case, what might be typical reasons, how can I specify some flexibility when I set `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can coerce `\baselineskip` to be a `<dimen>` by multiplying it by 1 and then adding the stretch and shrink components:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

or use `\glueexpr`:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\glueexpr\baselineskip + 0pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

The latter would preserve possible components in `\baselineskip` and add to them; the former would kill the stretch and shrink components in `\baselineskip`.

Comment: That works man, I thank you. I thought of that as well but I thought if I neglect the 1 before \baselineskip it would be there anyway by default.